# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chocolate' of undefined

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chocolate' of undefined
```

when building (`ng build --prod`) my Angular project with @clr version 0.12.6 and more.

Anybody got the same issue and if so, were you able to resolve it and how?

Anybody could tell me where the 'chocholate' property is used? That could help me to point out my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you let your code invisible? we should need the code visible first.

Comment: We can't feel what's wrong with your code. You should let us see

Comment: As the error explains you're trying to read a property from a null/undefined object. Without your code is impossible to tell you more.

Comment: @Francesco For sure, my code does not have that property and really seems to come from Clarity. I have no issue when running with version 0.12.5. For the code, not sure which part could cause that issue because I don't know where Clarity is using that property. :-(

Comment: Can you please create a reproduction of this behavior? I have no issues with a new project with Clarity 0.12.6. In the past this has happened when people didn't update modules correctly or switched branches with different versions installed. Reset node_modules and get a clean copy to help test that.

Also `chocolate` properties are for internal APIs. Are you also using Angular 6?

Comment: Hi @JeremyWilken,  I am using angular 6.1. Uninstall and reinstall the 2 Clarity modules without success. I will see with a clean node_modules if I see the issue.

Comment: Hi again @JeremyWilken. Finally, by cleaning up all the node_modules and install everything back worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes your node modules get out of sync, try deleting the directory and reinstalling. I recommend using NPM 5+ or Yarn to get a proper lock file to help keep this in sync better.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, by cleaning up all the node_modules directory and install everything again worked perfectly!